# mvc 4 google openid migrate users to mvc 5 identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-identity

of my 2k users on my mvc 4 app, 300+ of them are using the google openid as per mvc 4 simplemembership. i found a migration sql script that imported my users to the mvc 5 identity db tables and all logins work perfectly except for google as i noticed that my google folks aren't able to login anymore.

digging deeper, after the vs 2013 update 2, it looks like they want me to use google oauth2 + google is deprecating openid 2 so i need to migrate my users further from openid to oauth2 for google.

has someone run into this? should i just say sorry to those google openid users and ask them to redo their logins to it's oauth2 now via google (i don't like that but).

if you ran into this, wondering how you handled this in your app??@!